# Is it possible to use 「にあたらない」 with nouns?

Tags: grammar

「にあたらない」 means "is not worthy of" or "no need to do so" and generally used with words like 「褒める」、「嘆く」etc. (Reference: [にあたらない](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=ni+ataranai))

> 彼は同情するにあたらない。
>
> He is not worthy of sympathy. / You don't need to show any sympathy for him.

Would it be possible to use this grammar with nouns? For example;

> 彼は同情にあたらない。(Excluding する)
>
> He is not worthy of your sympathy.

or

> 泣かないでくれ。彼は君の涙にあたらないよ。(Using 涙)
>
> Please don't cry. He is not worthy of your tears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「同情にあたらない」「涙にあたらない」 (noun+にあたらない) don't sound very natural to me... I would say:

> 「彼は同情するに(は)あたらない。」
>   「彼は同情に[値]{あたい}しない。」 He is not worthy of your sympathy.
>   「彼は君の涙に[値]{あたい}しない。」 He is not worthy of your tears.

... using 「verb+に(は)あたらない」 or 「noun+に[値]{あたい}しない」.

Comment: 「～するにあたらない」「～するにはあたらない」 both sound okay to me. According to 明鏡国語辞典: `《「～するに(は)あたらない」の形で》～するに(は)及ばない。～する必要はない。` and [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/4694/meaning/m0u/): `７（「…にあたらない」などの形で）…するに及ばない。「驚くにあたらない」「腹をたてるにはあたりません」`

Answer (score 3):

According to 三省堂{さんせいどう} 大辞林{だいじりん} 、「当{あ}たらない」should be used with verbs and it is not proper to be used with nouns.

[三省堂{さんせいどう} 大辞林{だいじりん}／あたら・ない 【当たらない】](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

> （ 連語 ）（「…するには当たらない」の形で）…する必要がない。…するのは適当でない。あたらぬ。 「驚くには－・ない」 → あたる

Additionally,「するに当たらない」sounds strange a bit for me. I think it is supposed to be 「するに**は**当たらない」. But I feel it still sounds clumsy for me. Indeed, it is correct; but it is still not common way to say it.

See this article.
[～までもない／～には及ばない／～にはあたらない](http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1797)

「あたらない」is usually used with something which has a power to condemn something such as rules, laws or common senses. Though it is not illegal to use with emotional action, I think it is better (for me) to rewrite as following :

- 同情には当たらない **good**
- → 同情するまでもない **better**
- → 同情には及ばない **better**

A proper word to use with **当たらない** which I can imagine right now is **失礼{しつれい}**.

- 失礼{しつれい}には当たらない **correct**
- → 失礼するまでもない **wrong**
- → 失礼には及ばない   **wrong**

If you want to use with 涙{なみだ}, I would rewrite as following :

- 涙に当たらない **incorrect**
- → 涙を流すまでもない **correct**
- → 涙を流すには及ばない **correct**

The phrase 涙を流すまでもない sounds that the third person is cruel. If it is intentional, that is okay. But if the person is not cruel or there is no third person in the situation, I think you can use ことはない .

- → 涙を流すまでもない **good**
- → 涙を流すことはない **better**

In fact, the phrase「涙を流すことはない」 is a very popular phrase in lyrics of Japanese songs.